# Why is my button not changing the location of my browser when it's inside a form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<form action="/" class="form" data-href="/User/Account/Login" id="loginForm" method="post">

            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div id="input-fields">
                <div>
                    <input class="big medium-margin" name="UserName" placeholder="Username (or guest)" size="25" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="big medium-margin" name="Password" placeholder="Password (or guest)" size="25" type="password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-input">
                    <div class="msg">Remember me?</div>
                    <input name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="white-gradient glossy">Login</button>
            <button class="white-gradient glossy" onclick="location.href='/User/Account/Register'">Register</button>
        </form>
```

When I click the Register but and then check with fiddler it is sending the following:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:81/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:81
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 199
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:81
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:81/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=gmYN0zBWRU2d1sxJz87-SvSFp4Klv4SeThVotN44K2RYOuJQ2

__RequestVerificationToken=mYmxLGhA2&UserName=&Password=&RememberMe=false
```

Can someone tell me why it's not just changing the location to /user/Account/Register ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the type of that button to `type="button"`, as a button has `type="submit"` as default, and will submit the form first.

```
<button type="button" class="white-gradient glossy" onclick="location.href='/User/Account/Register'">Register</button>
```